# Does bitcoin still concatenate the locking and unlocking script and execute?

Tags: transactions, script

Does bitcoin still concatenate the locking and unlocking scripts and execute in order to validate transaction or is validation done another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does bitcoin still concatenate the locking and unlocking scripts

No. This bug was fixed many years ago. ScriptSig and ScriptPubkey executed separately, not concatenated to each other

Comment: Does any cryptocurrency still do it besides bitcoin?

Comment: No, but you are welcome to create such bogus coin :) There are millions of bugs you can do yourself and/or find on github